# SQL Server multi-user from same computer?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a .NET SQL Server application that two people in different physical locations need to be able to run concurrently. Is it possible for both users to Remote Desktop to the same server, log in under different user accounts, then run the application, opening the same physical database?

I'm getting the message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database [databasename] requested by the login. The login failed

...when the second user attempts to open the database.

Comment: The logins need to have access to the database.  If you use windows authentication, then this is likely to work okay.

Comment: This is the connection string I'm using:  m_cn.ConnectionString = _
                 "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; " & _
                 "Database=MVIRS_ManagerSQL; " & _
                 "Integrated Security=True; " & _
                 "Connect Timeout=30;"

Comment: You really should put your connection string in the config file instead of recreating it everywhere in your application. Then when it changes you simply change the config entry.

Comment: Just tried opening the database from SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, and I'm getting "The database MVIRS_ManagerSQL is not accessible (Object Explorer)"

Comment: Is the database offline? In single user mode?

Comment: The connection string exists in one place only -- in a database class. The class opens the database in New, and disposes it in Dispose. The class is only instantiated via Using...End Using construct.

Comment: The database is not offline, and not in single user mode.

Comment: .. and the windows account that you are logged in with, has been granted the necessary access to the database?

Comment: Simen S, can you check me on this?  In Computer Management, Local Users and Groups, the second account is a member of Administrators and Users.  Is there a security setting in SQL Server that I should look at?  Remember I'm connecting with Integrated Security=True (which I think means Windows Authentication...).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for both users to Remote Desktop to the same server, log in under different user accounts, then run the application, opening the same physical database?

Yes.

> I'm getting the message: [...] when the second user attempts to open the database.

The error you are getting indicates that the second user logged in does not have permission to access the database. You can fix this by connecting to your SQL Server instance with SQL Server Management Studio and configuring the permissions appropriately. Remember that you will need to create

- the *login* for the user (on global SQL Server level) as well as
- the *user* in the database (on the database level).

An extensive introduction to SQL Server security is out of scope here, but plenty of tutorials can be found on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample connection string to help you pass the data:

```
<add name="TestDBConn" connectionString="data source=TestPC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyTestDB;user id=User1;password=p@ssw0rd;persist security info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Check if your security logins match what is within the SQL.